# My function in my class isn't mocked even though I use spyOn object on the instance and the method name

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have the following class:

```
class SomeCalculator {
  add(x,y) {
    console.log('add method is called')
    return x + y;
  }
}

function operationsFunc(y,x) {
  console.log(x,y)
  const calc = new SomeCalculator();
  console.log('calc', calc);
  calc.add(x,y);
}
```

I am calling `operationsFunc` and there I am calling the `add` method from my `SomeCalculator` class

When I am testing the `operationsFunc` method let's say that I don't want to test the `calc.add` method inside so I want to spy it and replace it with mock function

But when I try:

```
   describe('operationsFunc()', () => {
    it('add method ', () => {
      let calc = new SomeCalculator();
      let spyObj = spyOn(calc, 'add').and.stub();
      console.log('spyObj', spyObj);
      operationsFunc(2,2);
    })
  })
```

my real add method from the `calc` instance is called again - I can see the console logs.

How can I mock the add method so it will be called from my test?

Comment: You can't. There's no connection between the calculator in your test and the one in the implementation. What you've discovered is that your implementation isn't very testable because the function is too coupled to the class - invert the dependency, pass it a calculator to use, then the test double is easy to inject.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i can, i found a way

Comment: Check my answer that I found on other place for same problem

Answer (score 0):

So we can extend the prototype from the actual class and with that the method will be mocked

```
spyOn(SomeCalculator.prototype, 'add')
```